# Processing output of git log - preceding spaces before commit messages

Tags: git

I have noticed that git log on my system inserts exactly 4 space characters before showing commit message. Is this a standard? I need this information for processing output of git log.

A simplification would be to assume that a commit message line is any line that contains preceding spaces and text after it, but then I lose information such as actual whitespace in a commit message. If I know it will always be precisely 4 spaces before commit message, I can retrieve exact data.

I'm processing an output like this:

```
commit e7a3b259a072766d89e8d9e3fefb839860c2926b
Author: John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
Date: Tue Dec 15 19:26:04 2020 +0100

    commit message

    longer commit message.
    line 2
```

Comment: I think I'm going to take a look at --pretty=format

Comment: The --format option solves my problem. https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Comment: Can you write how you solved your issue as an answer to your own question ? To inidicate to readers (and answerers) that this question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

git log provides a --format option which allows to build a custom template for the output.

Using this I could build output which is easy to parse and predictable. Example in JavaScript:

```
  const formatTemplate = [
    '###COMMIT_START###',
    'id:%H',
    'authorName:%an',
    'authorEmail:%ae',
    'authorDate:%at',
    'cmomitterName:%cn',
    'committerEmail:%ce',
    'committerDate:%ct',
    'message:%s',
    'body:',
    '%b',
  ].join('%n'); // joins as one string glued by '%n'

  const gitLogCommand = `git --no-pager log --reverse --full-history --format="${formatTemplate}" --date-order --decorate=full --follow`;
```

git parses %n as a newline. For full list of placeholders, see https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats